# OpenGL ES - Most efficient texture format for the two colors: white and fully transparent

Tags: ios, opengl-es, format, textures

Currently I'm using ARGB to store these textures, but I know it's such a waste of memory.

Any recommendations on the best texture format for a texture that contains only two colors, when the two colors are only white and fully transparent pixels (alpha 0)?

EDIT: This is for iOS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a platform dependent question.  In the iOS sdk, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_2BPPV1_IMG is the most efficient way to store textures as you've described.

If you require uncompressed, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE type.